# Вопрос по работе с массивами

Tags: php, массивы

Я новичок в PHP, очень сложно разобраться в документации, поэтому решил задать сюда вопрос.

У меня есть такой массив:

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [0] => Array
>         (
>             [PRODUCT_ID] => 610
>             [OPTIONS] => Array
>                 (
>                     [OPTION_1] => 0
>                 )
>
>             [ADDS] => 
>             [AMOUNT] => 1
>             [SECTION_ID] => 62
>             [HISTORY_PRICE] => 720
>         )
>
>     [1] => Array
>         (
>             [PRODUCT_ID] => 609
>             [OPTIONS] => Array
>                 (
>                     [OPTION_1] => 0
>                 )
>
>             [ADDS] => 
>             [AMOUNT] => 1
>             [SECTION_ID] => 62
>             [HISTORY_PRICE] => 620
>         )
>
>     [2] => Array
>         (
>             [PRODUCT_ID] => 611
>             [OPTIONS] => Array
>                 (
>                     [OPTION_1] => 0
>                 )
>
>             [ADDS] => 
>             [AMOUNT] => 1
>             [SECTION_ID] => 62
>             [HISTORY_PRICE] => 750
>         )
>
>     [3] => Array
>         (
>             [PRODUCT_ID] => 613
>             [OPTIONS] => Array
>                 (
>                     [OPTION_1] => 0
>                 )
>
>             [ADDS] => 
>             [AMOUNT] => 1
>             [SECTION_ID] => 62
>             [HISTORY_PRICE] => 670
>         )
>
>     [4] => Array
>         (
>             [PRODUCT_ID] => 612
>             [OPTIONS] => Array
>                 (
>                     [OPTION_1] => 0
>                 )
>
>             [ADDS] => 
>             [AMOUNT] => 1
>             [SECTION_ID] => 62
>             [HISTORY_PRICE] => 670
>         )
> ```

Мне нужно записать **PRODUCT_ID** из всех этих массивов в другой массив, чтобы в другом массиве были просто **PRODUCT_ID**. Заранее, спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php) - Возвращает массив из значений одного столбца входного массива

Пример из документации:

```
$records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5342,
        'first_name' => 'Jane',
        'last_name' => 'Jones',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 5623,
        'first_name' => 'Peter',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    )
);

$first_names = array_column($records, 'first_name');
print_r($first_names);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => Sally
    [2] => Jane
    [3] => Peter
)
```

В вашем случае это будет

```
$productIds = array_column($myarray, 'PRODUCT_ID');
```

Answer (score -1):

Если я правильно понял вложенность массивов, то можно сделать обычным перебором, если в дальнейшем потребуется из массивов выбирать другие данные:

```
<?
$arr = [
    0 => [
        'PRODUCT_ID' => 22,
        'ADDS' => 22,
        'fdfd' => 22,
        'sdfgdsgds' => 22,
    ],
    1 => [
        'PRODUCT_ID' => 33,
        'ADDS' => 33,
        'fdfd' => 333,
        'sdfgdsgds' => 33,
    ],
    2 => [
        'PRODUCT_ID' => 44,
        'ADDS' => 44,
        'fdfd' => 44,
        'sdfgdsgds' => 44,
    ]
];
$new_arr = [];
foreach ($arr as $item){
    $new_arr[] = $item['PRODUCT_ID'];
}
var_dump($new_arr);
?>
```